# How do I make the login screens and boot splashes match when installing different desktops?

Tags: unity, lubuntu, kde, desktop-environments, display-manager

I wanted to try out different desktop environments so I installed XFCE, KDE, GNOME, etc on top of Unity in Ubuntu 12.04

After a while I decided that I didn't like those other DEs and would stick to Unity.
So I changed my default DE to Unity by configuring `gdm`.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Now I am able to choose my DE at login time and all of DEs are working properly.

But the strange thing is that my boot up screen says 'lubuntu', my login screen is KDE, and my desktop is Unity.

How and why is this happening? Why didn't my gdm configuration have any effect? Does login and boot up screen need to be configured separately from the DE?

*There are other similar questions here but they are not the same as this one. I do not want to remove the other enviroments I'm quite happy with having a list of DEs to select from. I want to know how to set proper defaults.*

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the Lubuntu splash screen in several ways.  If you want to change splash screens every once in a while you can run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

You will be presented with a screen like the following:

[image]

In this case, entering a <kbd>0</kbd> or a <kbd>1</kbd> will set the splash screen to the Kubuntu logo, while entering <kbd>2</kbd> will set it to the default Ubuntu logo.

If you want to get rid of the Lubuntu logo permanently, you can remove the package using:

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-lubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-lubuntu-text
```

Replacing `lubuntu` with the desktop environment you installed.

You might be asked to remove `lubuntu-desktop` that's OK, as its a [meta package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages).

If you've configured `gdm` using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` you shouldn't have a KDE (KDM) login screen.  If your login screen looks something like this:

[image]

Then try configuring `gdm` again.  If that doesn't work you can remove `kdm` with:

```
sudo apt-get remove kdm
```

Again, you might be asked to remove `kubuntu-desktop`.  Its also a meta package, so go ahead and remove it.

Comment: Is that the kdm display manager (login screen) that you've shown? AFAIK Kubuntu 12.10 now uses lightdm by default, although the OP does say "KDE" not "Kubuntu" specifically.

Comment: Good question.  It is a picture of `KDM`, and you are correct, after after looking it up, the new default for Kubuntu is `lightDM`.  However, if the OP configured `GDM` they shouldn't see any KDE styled login screen.

Answer (score 3):

try `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` to choose your boot screen.

I believe unity uses lightdm as default display manager so when you reconfigure lightdm you should get the default ubuntu login screen

Comment: LightDM is the default in 12.10.