# How can I restore the default Ubuntu splash screen?

Tags: plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make the login screens and boot splashes match when installing different desktops?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228876/how-do-i-make-the-login-screens-and-boot-splashes-match-when-installing-differen)

I recently changed my desktop environment to Gnome Shell and my login manager to GDM.

As I applied these changes, the splash screen shown at boot has changed too. Now I no longer see the Ubuntu logo with the purple background and the white dots, but instead the default Gnome wallpaper (blue stripes).

How can I restore the default splash screen?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/228876/44179